# IL Emit - redirecting a property

Tags: c#, emit

I'm trying to create a dynamic wrapper, but can fugire out my mistake.
Here is what I got:

Simple Data class:

```
public class Data
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; } = 42;
}
```

A Base class, providing a field for redirection:

> ```
>     public class WrapperBase<T> where T : new()
>     {
>         public WrapperBase()
>         {
>             Field = new T();
>         }
>         public T Field { get; set; }
>         public void Foo();
>     }
> ```

A class using the redirection base:

```
public class SomeDynamicClass : WrapperBase<Data> { }
```

and a class using it:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Content = MyFactory.Create<SomeDynamicClass>();
    }
    public object Content { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I want the factory to create:

```
public class DesiredResult : SomeDynamicClass
{
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return Field.MyProperty; }
        set
        {
            Field.MyProperty = value;
            Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the IL code and tried to recode it, but there is a mistake which I can not find. Here is what I got so far:

```
public class Factory
{
    private const String NAMESPACE = "vmproxy.{0}";
    public object Create<T>() where T : class
    {
        AssemblyName an = new AssemblyName();
        an.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        AssemblyBuilder ab = ad.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

        var _mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(an.Name);
        var fieldProp = typeof(T).GetProperty("Field");
        var modelType = typeof(T).GetProperty("Field").PropertyType;
        var name = typeof(T).Name;
        var tb = _mb.DefineType(String.Format(NAMESPACE, name), TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class, typeof(T));


        foreach (var property in modelType.GetProperties())
        {
            PropertyBuilder prop = tb.DefineProperty(property.Name, PropertyAttributes.None, property.PropertyType, null);
            MethodBuilder meth = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + property.Name,
                                                        MethodAttributes.Public |
                                                        MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                                                        MethodAttributes.Virtual |
                                                        MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                                                        property.PropertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
            ILGenerator ilGen = meth.GetILGenerator();
            Label endOfMethod = ilGen.DefineLabel();
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            //ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, fieldProp.GetGetMethod());
            ilGen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, fieldProp.GetGetMethod(), null);
            //ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, property.GetGetMethod());
            ilGen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, property.GetGetMethod(),null);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, endOfMethod);
            ilGen.MarkLabel(endOfMethod);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            prop.SetGetMethod(meth);

            //meth = tb.DefineMethod("set_" + property.Name,
            //                                MethodAttributes.Public |
            //                                MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
            //                                MethodAttributes.Virtual |
            //                                MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
            //                                null, new Type[] { property.PropertyType });
            //ilGen = meth.GetILGenerator();
            //ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            //TBD...
            break;
        }

        return Activator.CreateInstance(tb.CreateType());
    }
```

Seems like I am generating an invalid IL code... Is there a way to check the created IL code?...

*Edit: the IL Code I am trying to create:*

```
    .method public hidebysig specialname instance int32 
            get_IntProp() cil managed
    {
      // Code size       17 (0x11)
      .maxstack  1
      .locals init ([0] int32 V_0)
      IL_0000:  nop
      IL_0001:  ldarg.0
      IL_0002:  call       instance !0 class FactoryWrapper.WrapperBase`1<class FactoryWrapper.Data>::get_Field()
      IL_0007:  callvirt   instance int32 FactoryWrapper.Data::get_IntProp()
      IL_000c:  stloc.0
      IL_000d:  br.s       IL_000f
      IL_000f:  ldloc.0
      IL_0010:  ret
    } // end of method DerivedClass3::get_IntProp



.method public hidebysig specialname instance void 
        set_IntProp(int32 'value') cil managed
{
  // Code size       27 (0x1b)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  call       instance !0 class FactoryWrapper.WrapperBase`1<class FactoryWrapper.Data1::get_Field()
  IL_0007:  ldarg.1
  IL_0008:  callvirt   instance void FactoryWrapper.Data::set_IntProp(int32)
  IL_000d:  nop
  IL_000e:  ldarg.0
  IL_0014:  callvirt   instance void class FactoryWrapper.WrapperBase`1<class FactoryWrapper.Data1>::Foo()
  IL_0019:  nop
  IL_001a:  ret
} // end of method DerivedClass3::set_IntProp
```

*Edit:* Receiving "**Unknown local variablenumber at offset 0x000c**"

Comment: What tool are you using to check the IL? I'd Use ILDASM if i were you.  Bonus is its already in your system if you have visual studio.

Comment: Use `AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave`, *save* your assembly, then run PEVerify on it and/or disassemble it to see what you're doing wrong. (Obviously, you can stub out the saving bit when deploying it in production, but it's invaluable in the debugging stage.)

Comment: of course I use ILdasm...

Comment: when I try to save the generated assemlby, It appears to be pretty empty - just the manifest is there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I got the idea, the answer was pretty straight forward:

```
        ILGenerator ilGen = meth.GetILGenerator();

        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilGen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, fieldProp.GetGetMethod(), null);
        ilGen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, property.GetGetMethod(), null);
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        prop.SetGetMethod(meth);
```

The Code I used from ILDASM contained way to many stack opperations, which are not required and seem to be even wrong. No Idea why that code even works... What I posted works like a charm.

Comment: Cool. Were you viewing the IL in Debug Mode?

Comment: Nope - plan brain-debuigging ;) Any idea how to see emited IL Code while debuggung using VS 2015?